# No free dynos on heroku account?

Tags: heroku

As far as I know heroku gives you one dyno for free for your app. I uploaded an app but I have no dynos to assign to it.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) so Heroku will know what kind of Dynos you need and how to start your app. Then you'll be able to scale your Dynos.